# XPath does not pass brower compatibility checks in InfoPath 2007

Tags: infopath, infopath-forms-services

Why do the targetField attributes below fail the browser compatibility checker in InfoPath 2007. Is there another way to write the statement so that it will work on Browser Enabled forms?

```
<xsf:ruleSets>
     <xsf:ruleSet name="ruleSet_1">
          <xsf:rule caption="Rule 1" isEnabled="yes">
               <xsf:assignmentAction targetField="my:group1/my:group2[1]/my:field3" expression="my:field1"></xsf:assignmentAction>
          </xsf:rule>
          <xsf:rule caption="Rule 2" isEnabled="yes">
               <xsf:assignmentAction targetField="my:group1/my:group2[2]/my:field3" expression="my:field2"></xsf:assignmentAction>
          </xsf:rule>
     </xsf:ruleSet>
</xsf:ruleSets>
```

Answer (score 0):

Is the "my:" prefix defined somewhere in surrounding XML you have not shown us? If not, then that might be a reason. The XML you've shown us has no definition for "my:".

Comment: Yes, everything is valid and it works in the InfoPath client. However, it's not possible to "Browser Enable" this form because it does not pass the browser compatibility check.

Comment: @driven: Notice how you didn't answer my question? Could you now go back and answer it?

Comment: John, my sentence started with the word "Yes," which was in response to your question.

Comment: @driven: ok, if `my:` is defined, then I'm out of clues.